# Writing a function in MIPS with global variables?

Tags: assembly, global-variables, mips, mips32

```
frogger:
    jal teechar
    jal update_frog
    lw $t0,game_indicator
    li $t0, 0
```

Okay, this is the function. I have teechar and update_frog functions completely written and working. I understand the first two bullets but not sure on the last two. How would i write the last two bullets in MIPS?

HERE IS FUNCTION Instructions:

Write a MIPS function frogger that takes no arguments, and returns a character (to make 
testing easier).  It does the following:

- Call your teechar to read-and-echo a character c.
- Call your update_frog(c).
- If c is non-zero, store c in a global variable to indicate that the game is over, and how it 
  ended.  (You must initialize that global variable to zero, of course.)
- Return c.

Here is my code:

```
frogger:
    jal teechar
    jal update_frog
```

Sorry I am just having trouble thinking about how to do this :(

Comment: What specifically are you stuck on? Do you know how to store values to a location?

Comment: im stuck on the last two bullets. Yes, i am not exactly sure how to store the value of c

Comment: I find it impossible to believe you haven't found any resources detailing how to store values to memory locations: 30 seconds on Google and I found [this](http://logos.cs.uic.edu/366/notes/mips%20quick%20tutorial.htm). Does that help you get moving in the right direction? Doesn't your class have any instructional materials, TAs, other students, lectures, handouts, or *anything*?

Comment: I have been looking but i mean do i just need to put a label under the data section, is that considered a global variable? And do i need to load anything because i call update frog but how do i actually get that c out of the function? And yes i do go to class but the TA and professor and not helpful....and i am not the only one that thinks that in the class

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of a global variable, either you have to pass the arguement or use a special purpose register. Since you have specified the function takes no args, you will have to reserve a register to hold the value of c whenever frogger is called, which would then read the value from that register.

Its not a clean solution from the high level programming language, but you are in assembly right now and might as well get your hands dirty!